# Creating SQL Server function with REPLACE function within

Tags: sql-server, function, replace

I'm trying to create function that takes data from table, replaces certain characters and returns replaced data. Function will be executed when called for.

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_lat(@rawtxt NVARCHAR)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @raw_mon NVARCHAR(50);

    SELECT @raw_mon = REPLACE (r.mongol, N'ф', 'f')
    FROM Connection.dbo.raw r
    WHERE r.mongol = @rawtxt

    RETURN @raw_mon;
END;
GO

UPDATE [Connection].[dbo].[raw] 
SET [mongol] = dbo.convert_lat(mongol) 
WHERE [mongol] LIKE N'ф%';
```

After I execute the `UPDATE` statement, characters that supposed to be replaced are not replaced but whole row becomes null.

Comment: So, what is the issue ?

Comment: Are you having issues?  Glancing at it, it looks like accurate SQL code

Comment: Maybe you need a function that returns a table - TVF ? That code doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Try converting your scalar function to a table valued function, although it should work as it is now as long as your select retrieves just 1 row.

Comment: The main issue is that you didn't specify the size of your parameter. The default for a parameter is 1. ALWAYS specify the size. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, use ITVF function

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_lat(@rawtxt nvarchar (400))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
SELECT raw_mon = REPLACE (@rawtxt, N'ф', 'f')

GO
```

Use it:

```
SELECT R.* , F.raw_mon
FROM Connection.dbo.raw r
CROSS APPLY convert_lat (R.mongol) F
```

Comment: I will try it. Is it right way to include a lot of characters in : REPLACE (@rawtxt, N'ц,ч,ф', 'ts,ch,q')?

Comment: you can wrap each character with another replace, however it could be quiet long. if you need to replace a lot of characters it is best to work with a mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to define function *parameters*  with appropriate length

So,

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_lat(@rawtxt nvarchar) -- Will accept 1 length default
```

It would be instead

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_lat(@rawtxt nvarchar(255))
```

Comment: @Xass1on, this may fix your most immediate problem, but consider the answer from hkravitz as well. What it implies without really saying is that it doesn't seem to make sense for your function to contain a `SELECT ... FROM Connection.dbo.Raw` statement given that its only purpose appears to be to retrieve a string that you already have (in the `@rawtxt` parameter).